# Probability using integration

Tags: probability-distributions

A cloth of $10$ meter is to be randomly distributed among $3$ brothers. Find the probability that no one can get more than $4$ meter. (Cloth may be distributed as $3.5$m, $3.5$m and $3$m. Or $3.2$m, $3.8$m and $3$m)

Comment: Please clarify the probability distribution.

Comment: is the length of the cloth continuous or some sorta discrete?

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the length to 1. Pick two points a, and b with these constraints:
$a<1, b<1, a+b<1$.  Assuming uniform distribution, on cartesian coordinates, this corresponds to a triangle.  Now, add the constraint that you want $\max(a,b,1-(a+b))<x.$
For $x<\frac12$, this area will be $\frac{x^2}2$.  Therefore the probability is $x^2$.  Plugging your units will give $p=0.16$. Should be straigtforward to convert this to integration since what we done is simple area calculation.